# 2 XAMLs using the same ViewModel class, but 2 separate instances

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a big long xaml. I then created a UserControl for the menu part of the xaml to make it clean (I think).  In my main xaml codebehind, I instantiated my ViewModel class and set it as the DataContext of the main xaml. In order to let main and menu xaml communicate to each other, I chose to use the same view model as the data context of the menu codebehind. I instantiated another ViewModel class. The my code works fine so far.

I 'feel' I am not doing this right, however. I believe I only need one instance of the ViewModel instance. But because the main.xaml.cs and the menu.xaml.cs don't know each other, I don't know how to share the instance.

Comment: Can't you put your view model property in App.xaml.cs class ?

Comment: I don't know how. In the constructor of the main.xaml.cs, I have `myViewModel = new MyViewModel(); this.DataContext = myViewModel();` I use the same lines for the menu.xaml.cs.

Comment: Alot of the [MVVM frameworks](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5069783/which-mvvm-framework-is-the-best-framework-for-wpf-apps) has an [IoC container](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991965.aspx) which let's you resolve the same instance of your ViewModel or inject it through the constructors.

Comment: @Martin : I added an answer to your question on how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a property to your App.xaml.cs and then bind to it in your controls.

**1st approach :** as a XAML resource

Your model:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public int Hello { get; set; }    
}
```

App.xaml.cs:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApplication12.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:wpfApplication12="clr-namespace:WpfApplication12"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        <wpfApplication12:MyViewModel x:Key="MyViewModel" />
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Small note: there is no need to annotate the object with `x:Shared="True"` as it is the default value, the same instance will be returned. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970778.aspx

Your user control :

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication12.UserControl2"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource MyViewModel}}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Hello}" />
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Now since your model is a resource, you can retrieve it by creating a property :

```
public MyViewModel MyViewModel
{
    get { return Application.Current.FindResource("MyViewModel") as MyViewModel; }
}
```

(you might want to store that reference in a field, however.)

**2nd approach :** as a conventional property

If for some reasons you prefer a conventional property, here's the syntax:

Note, the property is static and initialized in the static constructor.

```
public partial class App : Application
{
    static App()
    {
        MyViewModel = new MyViewModel();
    }

    public static MyViewModel MyViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

Binding to it in your user control:

```
<Grid DataContext="{Binding Source={x:Static wpfApplication12:App.MyViewModel}}"/>
```

Comment: your answer makes sense. I tried, but got an error at line `<wpfApplication12:MyViewModel x:Key="MyViewModel" />`. The error message is _Cannot not create an instance of "MyViewModel"_. I assume this line can be placed in any type of child control because my main.xaml here is an UserControl. I put in in `<UserControl.Resources>`.

Comment: I solved the problem by removing two lines from the constructor of MyViewModel. `_MyDoc = new XmlDocument(); _MyDoc.Load(_PathToReport);` I don't know why these two lines cause the problem.

Comment: Here is another problem. In the line: `<Grid DataContext="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource MyViewModel}}">`, I got _The resource "MyViewModel" cannot be resolved_ error.

Comment: Do you still have the error ? Sometimes until you build again, VS complains of not finding the resource. If you can't get it right, paste your problematic code.

Comment: I probably misunderstood your answer. I fixed it now. In my App.xaml (I thought it was in the menu.xaml), I have `<local:MyMenu DataContext="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource MyViewModel}}" />`.

Answer (score 0):

You could have another view which wraps both your `MenuView` and `MainView`, and set the `DataContext` on the wrapper view, then both your `MenuView` and `MainView` will inherit and use the same `DataContext`.

Sample XAML for Wrapper View:

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication1.YourView"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:wpfApplication1="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <wpfApplication1:YourMenuView Grid.Row="0"/>
        <wpfApplication1:YourMainView Grid.Row="1"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

and Codebehind for WrapperView:

```
public partial class YourView : UserControl
{
    public YourView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new YourViewModel();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put both of your usercontrol into the `MainWindow.Xaml` and set the data context in `MainWindow.xaml.cs` or expose a static property in your viewmodel of the viewmodeltype like this:

```
public class ViewModel
{
   private static ViewModel instance = new ViewModel();

   public static Viewmodel Instance
   {
       get
       {
          return instance;
       }
   }
}
```

in your xaml.cs you can do the following:

```
DataContext = ViewModel.Instance;
```

You can repeat this line in any number of `xaml.cs`'s, for all the XAML now you'll have only one instance.

Comment: Actually it's XAML, not XMAL ! :-)